# Как получить список учебных предметов для студента с помощью LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть, примерно, такая схема на C# и EntityFramework Core (v. 5.0.11):

```
// Студент 
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

// Учебный предмет
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public List<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

// Учебный предмет, который выбрал студент
public class StudentSubject
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}

public class ApiDbContext : DbContext
{
    // Список студентов
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set;}

    // Список учебных предметов
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    // Список учебных предметов, выбранных студентами
    public DbSet<StudentSubject> StudentSubjects { get; set;  на }

    //...
}
```

Как с помощью LINQ to SQL получить список предметов (Subjects в классе Student), которые выбрал студент? Понятно, что можно отфильтровать StudentSubjects по StudentId, а дальше?

P.S. Смущает то, что добавление связей "многие-ко-многим" приводит к добавлению дополнительных столбцов в таблицу БД, которые мне не нужны. Например, к таблице Subjects добавляется столбец StudentsId, а ведь один предмет могут выбрать несколько студентов.

Comment: Хм, это должна быть связь многие-ко-многим (many-to-many)? В классе `Student` имеется `List<Subject> Subjects`. А в классе `Subject` тогда должен быть `List<Student> Students`.

Comment: В свойстве `Subjects` уже хранятся выбранные студентом предметы. Никаких дополнительных усилий не нужно для их получения.

Comment: И `StudentSubject` можно убрать, он за кулисами сам создаст связующую таблицу.

Comment: `StudentSubject` - это join entity - промежуточная сущность. Её в принципе можно вообще явно не создавать в вашем случае. Документация: [Many-to-many](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: А есть без Core старше 4 версии?

Comment: _а ведь один предмет могут выбрать несколько студентов_ - поэтому в сущности `Subject` должно быть свойство `List<Student> Students`.

Comment: "поэтому в сущности Subject должно быть свойство List<Student> Students" - это избавит от лишних столбцов?

Comment: Вы документацию смотрели? Я вам ссылки дал. Вы свойство `List<Student> Students` добавили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания связи многие-ко-многим (many-to-many) достаточно в сущностях создать навигационные свойства-коллекции.
В классе `Student` делаем свойство `List<Subject> Subjects`.
В классе `Subject` делаем свойство `List<Student> Students`.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
public class ApiDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

При этом в БД автоматически будут созданы три таблицы: Students, Subjects и StudentSubject.
Теперь при добавлении сущностей в навигационные свойства связи между ними будут создавать тоже автоматически.

---

Возможно, у вас возникли сложности при получении связанных сущностей.
Например:

```
var student = db.Students.First(x => x.Name == "StudentA");
```

При выполнении этих запросов навигационные свойства окажутся пустыми. Дело в том, что связанные данные не загружаются по умолчанию. Это нужно сделать явно.
[Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Самый распространённый способ - Eager Loading.
Для этого добавим метод `Include` в запрос:

```
var student = db.Students.Include(x => x.Subjects).First(x => x.Name == "StudentA");
```

Теперь предметы будут загружены.

---

> Смущает то, что добавление связей "многие-ко-многим" приводит к добавлению дополнительных столбцов в таблицу БД, которые мне не нужны.

Это столбцы нужны движку реляционной СУБД. Без них невозможно связать данные из разных таблиц между собой.

---

Подробнее смотрите документацию:
Relationships: [Many-to-many](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many).
Changing Foreign Keys and Navigations: [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes#many-to-many-relationships).

Промежуточную сущность при желании можно создать и использовать. Но обычно это делают только при добавлении в неё дополнительных данных:
[Join entities with payloads](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes#join-entities-with-payloads).

Можете ознакомиться с туториалом EF Core with MVC. В нём показан пример применения промежуточной сущности с полезной нагрузкой.
[Many-to-Many relationships](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0#many-to-many-relationships).